# How to capture an key press even from Custom view class in android?

Tags: android, menu

In my android application, i have used custom view to load as the view of an activity.Now i want to detect whether user clicks on menu button or not.hope following code will explain the scenario.

**My Custom View Class:**

```
 public class LibraryHomeView extends LinearLayout implements OnKeyListener {
//variable dec goes here..
public LibraryHomeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);  

    init(context,attrs);
}

private void init(Context con,AttributeSet att) {
    //custom view implementation goes here...
}
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
         Log.d(TAG, "KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU");
            return true;
        }

}
```

My problem is i do not want to capture this event from activity class i want to captuer this from view class but when i press the menu key it will not come to `OnKey()` method.Any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // do something...
   }
    return true;
   }
```

**EDIT**

```
public class LibraryHomeView extends LinearLayout {

     public LibraryHomeView(Context context) {
     super(context);
     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   setFocusable(true);
  }
```

Comment: i tried with both "OnKeyUp" and "onKeyDown" but nothing happen.

Comment: nope but when i press menu key it will not come to the methods.

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/379-how-to-capture-key-events-custom-views) . Hope it helps

Comment: i added  setFocusable(true); on my constructor it solved my problem. thank you very much for your link @Parth Doshi

Answer (score 0):

If you can capture the key event in your activity, then is simple to pass it to the view. Just call from the activity a method inside the view. You may have something like this (I don't have eclipse on this computer, so I code directly in browser - I may have syntax errors):

```
public class LibraryHomeView extends LinearLayout {

//......

    public void keyEventRecieved(String eventMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, eventMessage);
    }
//.......
}
```

and inside the activity:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {
LibraryHomeView control;
//......
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        control = (LibraryHomeView)findViewById(R.id.myCustomViewId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
             Log.d(TAG, "KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU");
             control.keyEventRecieved("Yahooooo!");
                return true;
            }

    }



//......

}
```